# Tooltip for matplotlib stacked bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

Is there a way to add tooltips to a stacked bar plot in matplotlib? I would like to use only matplotlib. My stacked bar plot has more than ten bars in each position. I would like to have a tooltip for each stacked bar. I have seen the question [matplotlib-stacked-bar-chart-and-tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50788421/matplotlib-stacked-bar-chart-and-tooltip) but the answer there uses mpldatacursor and I would like to use only matplotlib. In addition, I will have more than two bars in each position, as already mentioned.

What I want to achieve is shown in the figure below. The bars with less than 10% will have no label but a tooltip showing information about them. The tooltip will be displayed with a mouse hover event.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matplotlib - Stacked bar chart and tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50788421/matplotlib-stacked-bar-chart-and-tooltip)

Comment: @Diziet Asahi. I have edited the question. I would like to use only matplotlib. In addition, I have more than two bars in each position.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50560525/i-want-to-display-the-values-of-x-and-y-while-hover-mouse-over-the-bar-graph/50560826#50560826) for how to show annotations upon hovering with the mouse.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I am aware of the answer you mention but that did not work for my stacked bar plot. Actually, I do not know how the example in the answer works since bar does not have a contain method.